# Can't insert values into a table, because of false database constraint

Tags: c#, oracle, constraints

I'm having a problem. I have an Oracle database setup with three tables, the first one is `project`, the second is `skill` and the third one is `requiredskill`, which is a link between the first two tables. Both their primary keys are in the third table as a foreign key.

At a certain point in my program, I create a `project` and save it in the database. Directly after that I insert two values into the `requiredskill` table, a certain primary key of the `skill` table and the primary key of the just created project.

I insert the data with the following code:

```
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("projID", project.ProjId));
    foreach (Skill skill in skills)
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("skillID", skill.SkillID));
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO REQUIREDSKILL VALUES(:skillID, :projID)";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (OracleException)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
```

As soon as I execute the the query, an `OracleException` gets caught and tells me that the project ID (the primary key of the `project` table) does not exist, however, with breakpoints I have verified that the data is in the table at the time of execution. Does anyone have an answer for this?

Comment: Are you opening and closing the connection for every single insert? That seems to be inefficient.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Now you mention it, I should change that.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the CREATE TABLE statements for you tables, including all constraints.  Thanks.

Comment: have you got the exact oracle error, including the error code?

Answer (score 3):

Your insert statement would be more robust with the syntax:

```
insert into requiredskill (skillid, projectid) values ( ...)
```

... as you might have the columns in the wrong order.

Comment: Tried it, it does make it more robust but it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this to be a transactional issue: If inserting  the project ID is done in one (uncommitted) transaction, while inserting the rquired skills is done in an other, the latter will fail.

Make sure you commit the first transaction and retry.

Comment: I'm not sute that making the two inserts different transactions is the answer, not in Oracle at least. The insert of the project and the required skills is arguably one business transaction and ought to either be commited or rolled back together. Perhaps the project is being inserted in a different session, in which case commiting it would allow the code to work, but it would be better n a asingle session and single transaction I think.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I didn't mean "Do it in 2 Transactions", but "Maybe you are doing it in 2 Transactions and don't know". I didn't include any business logic in my answer, only the technical idea.

Comment: I have tried to commit the first transaction, still got the same error.